# How to use the Android lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to create an Android application that interacts with the user when the phone is locked
For example the Sony Xperia U (android 4.something)  the default mp3 player displays in the lock screen, above the pattern, the name of the song and buttons play, pause, next. In Huawei P8 lite the player displays the aforementioned buttons + the background picture album in an separate screen when you press the power button, and when you slide, it shows the pattern.
I want to do something similar,  to display messages from the application to the user, who can press buttons to interact with the application when the phone is locked.
Can this be done without creating new lock screen; (I'm afraid I will do something stupid and lock myself out)
If yes, what activities / permissions / libraries etc should be used;

Comment: so,you are saying I can't just use my app with the deafult lock screen?

Comment: @AHoneyBustard please explain the purpose of sharing that link. How does it help the OP?

Comment: I join the question, in the link provided only full source code. If anyone can show up the principle and not be doushbag that votes down everything, it could help us.